# How to Route in OpenVPN on the basis of Domain Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc, openvpn, vpc

I have a OpenVPN Server that basically routes traffic from client to some of the Static IP Address Websites through VPN with help of hostname and netmask and for making that Static IP accessible through VPN I just have to add the corresponding CIDR block to VPN Server Config to pass the traffic through it.

For e.g If I want to add some set of ips(10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0) to pass the traffic through VPN, I just need to add the following line.

`push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0"`

But What if I have an endpoint with some domain name whose ip keeps on changing. For e.g S3 Static Website Hosting, Amazon API Gateway.

Can I route traffic to these custom domains via the VPN.

I tried to search a lot, but wasn't able to find any feasible solution